# How can i put javascipt code as it is into javascript string variable?

Tags: javascript

I have below code

```
<script>
let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
</script>
```

I am trying to put above code into string variable just like below

```
var all_script="<script>
var text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.replace("Jordan", "Adam");
</script>";
console.log(all_script);
```

But its not working .
Any answer ?

Answer (score 0):

1. quotes.
2. newlines
3. escape the end script `<\/script>` if the script is inline in a page since it will interfere with the wrapping script tags.

You can use template literal backticks to handle 1 and 2:

```
   const all_script = `<script>
     let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
   <\/script>;`
```

and if the script is in an external file, you do not need to escapee the `</script>`